# How can i ignore empty row when reading a Kendo Grid data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid . I add and empty row on the bottom. 
I use grid.dataSource.data() to read the grid data into a JSON object.

But it includes the empty row . How can igonore the row ?

Do i need to traverse the grid and build a object like below ?

```
        var data = grid.dataSource.data();

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].FirstName.trim() != "") {
                var obj = {};
                obj.FirstName = data[i].FirstName;
                obj.UserId = data[i].UserId;
            }
        }
```

Or use filtering

```
        var data= grid.dataSource.data();
        var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
        var filters = dataSource.filter({ field: "FirstName", operator: "neq", value: "" });
        var allData = dataSource.data();
        var query = new kendo.data.Query(allData);
        var data = query.filter(filters).data;
```

But the issue with this aswell is that filters is not applied.

None seem to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `operator: 'isnotempty'`

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 32 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 20 },
    { name: "", age: 10 }
  ]
});
dataSource.filter( { field: "name", operator: "isnotempty"});
```

[Is not empty filter](https://dojo.telerik.com/UviYEPay)